# How can I use FIND_IN_SET within a JOINED table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, find-in-set

I have 2 tables:

- **user**: names of registered blood donors with their blood type.
- **blood**: contains blood types and blood compatibilities. e.g.: Blood id 5 (A-) can receive blood donations from 5 (A-) and 6 (O-).

I have to build a search form that retreives potential blood donors. The form allows the user to search for specific blood type donors. If I search for blood type 5 (A-), the query should return all users that have 5 (A-) and 6 (O-) blood types, and the resulting list should display both the name and the blood type of each user.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT user.name, blood.name AS blood FROM user JOIN blood ON blood.id_blood = user.id_blood WHERE user.id_blood = 5
```

This only brings other users that have the exact blood type as searched, but not all the compatible blood types.

Then, I tried this other query. This will search all compatible blood types but the results are also filtered by the blood type (blood type 6 records should also be displayed because the `receive` column of blood id 5 contains `5,6`.)

```
SELECT user.name AS name, blood.name AS blood FROM user JOIN blood ON blood.id_blood = user.id_blood WHERE FIND_IN_SET(5, blood.receive)
```

...but for some reason it's not displaying the correct rows. I'm seeing some A+, AB+, A- records, and there should only be A- and O- records.

Here are tables' structures in [jsfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edfb99/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `find_in_set()` in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT u.name AS name, b.name AS blood
FROM user u JOIN
     blood b
     ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id_blood, b.receive) > 0;
```

However, you should really have a separate table with one row per blood type and each type that can be received.  This is called a *junction table*.  Storing lists in comma-separated strings is not the SQL way of doing things:  tables are.

EDIT:

Like this:

```
SELECT u.name AS name, b.name AS blood
FROM user u JOIN
     blood b
     ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id_blood, b.receive) > 0
WHERE u.id_blood = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But would it be possible with the current schema?

Comment: @andufo . . . That is in the answer.

Comment: actually it's not working. Answers are being repeated and that query won't let me filter by a specific blood type.

Comment: @andufo . . . Just add an additional `where` if you need more filtering conditions.

Comment: sorry for asking this several days after, but, i'm getting repeated results, any idea why?

Comment: Can you ask another question and set up a SQL Fiddle showing the duplicated results?